# Would a BMS help discharge the 18650s individually at an equal rate when they are connected in series?

Tags: batteries, bms

I'm wondering if I should add a BMS to my battery pack.

I got 11x18650 with built protection in series, and have noticed that some of them get discharged quicker than others, and because of built in protection, they just kill the whole pack when just one of them goes down below a certain voltage.

I've googled what a BMS does, but couldn't find any info on this functionality.
Also I would appreciate any aliexpress/ebay links to a cheap BMS that does this, thanks!

Comment: It will discharge the ones that are higher voltage than the others.

Comment: Ok, so it will basically do what I need it to do?